# Pandas long to wide with values filled based on answer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dataframe from long to wide, but Im not sure how to convert it to the format below. What am I missing?

```
d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'vote2': [10, 2,18,26,77,99,9,40], 
     'ballot1': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
    'voteId':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
#########################################################

dftemp=df1

#####FORMATTING DATA
dftemp=pd.DataFrame(dftemp.reset_index())
dflw= dftemp.set_index(['voteId','vote','ballot1'])
dflw=dflw.unstack()
dflw.columns = dflw.columns.droplevel(0).rename('')
dflw=pd.DataFrame(dflw)
print(dflw)
```

MY CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
               a    b     a     b
voteId vote                      
1      100   0.0  NaN  10.0   NaN
2      50    NaN  1.0   NaN   2.0
```

GOAL:

```
voteid (ballot1=a)vote (ballot1=b)vote (ballot1=a)vote2 (ballot1=b)vote2
1               100             NaN             10               NaN
2               NaN             50              NaN              2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am starting from df1

```
s=df1.set_index(['voteId','ballot1']).unstack()
s.columns=s.columns.map('(ballot1={0[1]}){0[0]}'.format) 

s
Out[1120]: 
        (ballot1=a)vote  (ballot1=b)vote  (ballot1=a)vote2  (ballot1=b)vote2
voteId                                                                      
1                 100.0              NaN              10.0               NaN
2                   NaN             50.0               NaN               2.0
3                   1.0              NaN              18.0               NaN
4                  23.0              NaN              26.0               NaN
5                   NaN             55.0               NaN              77.0
6                  67.0              NaN              99.0               NaN
7                  89.0              NaN               9.0               NaN
8                   NaN             44.0               NaN              40.0
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, but can you explain how the 0[0] formatting resulted in the correct column name value, and how 0[1] resulted in the correct a or b value?

Comment: @Rilcon42 opps , you can change to `s.columns=s.columns.map('(ballot1={0[1]}){0[0]}'.format)`